# Will the CDC MFC Class member function DPtoHIMETRIC() functionality varies between Windows 7 and Windows XP?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Will the CDC (an MFC class) MFC Class member function DPtoHIMETRIC() functionality varies between Windows 7 and Windows XP??
Below is the sample code:

//calculate the bounding rectangle in HIMETRIC units
//logical unit = 0.01 mm and value of lpDrawItemStruct is passed as function argument

```
CDC pDC= CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
pDC->SetMapMode(MM_HIMETRIC);
CSize wh(rc.Width(),rc.Height());
pDC->DPtoHIMETRIC(&wh);
int x = wh.cx;
int y = wh.cy;
```

**After conversion the values(x and y) in Windows XP varies with Windows 7. Due to that functionality is getting affected. Kindly provide your suggestions and views in handling this issue.**

Reference:
**For CDC class**
*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73(v=vs.80).aspx*
**For DPtoHIMETRIC**
*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6e91ee5(v=vs.80).aspx*

Comment: Where do you get the values for `rc`?

Comment: rc is of type CRect. it's value is retrieved from CRect rc(lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem);

Answer (score 4):

From the linked MSDN article:

> the conversion is based on the number of pixels in the physical inch

Which is affected by the video adapter's DPI setting.  Yes, commonly higher on Windows 7 since it is so easy to change:

[image]

The "Set custom text size (DPI)" link produces:

[image]

Resetting the settings is likely to make your program operate correctly again.  Or bump it way up, Windows will start taking care of scaling old non DPI-aware apps at 150%.  At a cost of producing fuzzy output.  These are not real fixes of course.  Writing code that scales graphics smoothly at different DPI settings requires work.

Comment: Sidenote: Writing Windows UI code that seamlessly adapts to the DPI of the system *almost* qualifies as an exercise in futility... It can be done, but it takes a lot of work and creates a lot of frustration.